# Is it possible to do a inverse match using yq

Tags: linux, yq

i wanted to do inverse match of a yml as below

Input yml content :

```
....
....

validate-common-non-production:
  stage: validate-common-non-production

deploy-common-non-production:
  stage: deploy-common-non-production

validate-common-production:
  stage: validate-common-production

deploy-common-production:
  stage: deploy-common-production

...
...
```

expected output :

```
....
....

validate-common-non-production:
  stage: validate-common-non-production

deploy-common-non-production:
  stage: deploy-common-non-production
...
...
```

can this be archived using yq, i want to remove all the objects ending with production but excluding the ones having non-production. also using regex rather than using full key name to select

Answer (score 0):

As you've used the [yq](/questions/tagged/yq) tag, please follow [its requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) and specify which implementation of `yq` you are targeting: [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) written in Python or [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) written in Go. Ideally, also indicate the version used.

> all the objects ending with production but excluding the ones having non-production

Also, it's not clear from the question whether you want to test against the top-level object's keys or the values of the child object's `.stage` key.

I'm going to address some of the possible combinations. Please clarify if your intended one is missing.

With kislyuk/yq, you can use `endswith` and `not` to make negative ascertainments. Access the top-level `.key` using `with_entries`.

```bash
yq -y 'with_entries(select(.key | endswith("non-production") or (endswith("production") | not)))'
```

Or, if you want to use regular expressions, use `test` with `$` to find final matches, and compile a negative lookbehind using `?<!`.

```bash
yq -y 'with_entries(select(.key | test("(?<!non-)production$") | not))'
```

To use the `.stage` value instead, replace `.key` with `.value.stage` inside `with_entries`.

As for mikefarah/yq, it unfortunately doesn't implement `endswith`. And while regular expressions are implemented, negative lookbehinds don't seem to be supported. But you can use globbing with `*` instead.

```bash
yq 'del(.[] | select(key == "*production" and key != "*non-production"))'
```

To use the `.stage` value instead, replace `key` with just `.stage`.

Given your (rectified) sample input, all of these output:

```yaml
validate-common-non-production:
  stage: validate-common-non-production
deploy-common-non-production:
  stage: deploy-common-non-production
```

Tested with kislyuk/yq v3.2.3 and mikefarah/yq v4.35.1